# Store web element&#39;s value in a parameter and use it in various js files in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, global-variables, testcafe

In our insurance domain, the below scenario we want to achieve using testcafe:-

1st file:- Login into the application
2nd file:- create a claim, store the claim number into the global variable
3rd file:- use that globally declared claim number in all the Testscripts.

we are using the Page object model to achieve our scenario.

Please let us know how can we achieve this in testcafe.
As we suspect, the web element value that we get in 2nd file gets vanished as soon as the test case gets executed. so how can we pass that web element value in our 3rd file?
If possible, please let us know the steps in detail.

we have tried the below keywords to define our selector but it didn't work.

1. global
2. globalthis

   We want to pass the data(fetched web element value) from one testscript to another testscript. Our question is whether it's possible or not

   **//page.js**

   import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
   class PageModel {
   constructor() {
   global.ClaimNumber = Selector('#Txt_claimnumber');
   //selector for Claim Number

   this.DateOfEvent = Selector('#dateofevent');
   //selector for Date of Event

   this.DateOfClaim = Selector('#dateofclaim')
   //selector for Date of Claim

   this.TimeOfEvent = Selector('#timeofevent')
   //selector for Time of Event

   this.TimeOfClaim = Selector('#timeofclaim')
   //selector for Time of Claim

   this.ClaimStatus = Selector('#claimstatus')
   //selector for Claim Status

   this.Save = Selector('#Save');
   //selector for Save Button

   }};

   export default new PageModel();

   **//test.js**

   import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

   import PageModel from './page';

   fixture`Getting Started`

   .page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

   var claimid;//claimid will be generate after saving a claim

   test('My first test', async t => {
   await t
   .typeText(this.DateOfEvent, '20/09/2022')

   .typeText(this.DateOfClaim, '20/09/2022')

   .typeText(this.TimeOfEvent, '12:00')

   .typeText(this.TimeOfClaim, '12:00')

   .typeText(this.ClaimStatus, 'xyz')

   .click(this.Save)

   claimid=global.ClaimNumber.value

   //After saving the claim we want to fetch claimid and want to use that claim id in another testscript

   });

**//test1.js**

import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

import PageModel from './page';

import Test from './test'

fixture`Getting Started`

.page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test('My first test', async t => {

var claimid1='23445';
await t.expect(claimid1).eql('claimid');

//want to verify claimid getting from test.js is equal to claimid from test1.js or not

//this is just an example but our requirement is to use claimid (getting from test.js) for different different operation into test1.js testscript.

});

Could you please tell us how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't correct to use information from one test in another one. If you want to prepare something before any test starts, you can use [hooks](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/intermediate-guides/hooks?search#header). Also, if you need to reuse auth information, use [Roles](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/intermediate-guides/authentication?search#header). It will be great practice.

Please see the following example with a global variable:

```js
//test.js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import PageModel from './page';

 

fixture`Getting Started`
    .page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

 

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(global.developerNameSelector, 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button')

 

        // Use the assertion to check if the actual header text is equal to the expected one
        .expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText).eql('Thank you, John Smith!');
});
```

```js
//page.js
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

 

class PageModel { 
    constructor() { 
        global.developerNameSelector = Selector('#developer-name'); 
    } 
}; 

 

export default new PageModel();
```

Comment: we are using roles to preserve our logging URL but we didn't come across with hooks. Now our problem statement is we want to abstract a web element value from a Testscripts and want to use it in different Testscripts. we just want to know is it achievable or not. if yes, then pls let us know how can we do that.

Comment: You can use [`fixtureCtx`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402701/reference/test-api/testcontroller/fixturectx) to exchange information from one test to another within one fixture. Also, you can use opportunities and declare a global variable. However, I highly don't recommend setting dependencies between tests.

Comment: could you please tell us the global variable things with example and we are using page object model.
How we have tried, we have created one file 'SelectorFile_Testcafe' and we have written below code in that file.

import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

    class c {

        constructor() {
            global.Selector_name = Selector('#id');    
        }

    };

    export default SelectorFile_Testcafe;

we are not able to access the selector in another file,but if we use 'this' keyword instead of global we are able to access selector

Comment: //page.js                                                                                                                                           
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

class PageModel {
    constructor() { 
        global.developerNameSelector = Selector('#developer-name'); 
    } 
};                                                                                                                              
  export default new PageModel();

Comment: In the continuation of above comment    //test.js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import PageModel from './page'; 

fixture`Getting Started`
    .page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`; 
var x;
test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(global.developerNameSelector, 'John Smith')
        .click('#submit-button')
      x=   await t.expect(Selector('#article-header').innerText)
}); 

Now our question is we want to use that value of variable x into a new js file(test1.js).

Answer (score 1):

As my colleague mentioned above, it is very bad practice to use data from one test in another one. However, if it is required, you can use the "global" object in a common JavaScript way to accomplish this task:

```js
test('My first test', async () => {
global.someVar = 'developer-name';
});

test('My second test', async t => {
await t.typeText(`#${global.someVar}`, 'some text');
});
```

Note that if, for some reason, the order in which the tests are executed changes (for example, in concurrency mode), then you will encounter unexpected behavior.

Also, I just checked your code and found out that you are trying to save the result of the "expect" method call (Assertion object) to your variable. Would you please clarify why? What behavior are you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your reply. please check our edited question. we have mentioned code snippets exactly what we want to automate.

Comment: I see a mistake in your example. You cannot get a selector value in this way `global.Claim Number.value` because of the following:
1. To execute the selector you need to call it with `await` because `Selector('#Text_claim number')` returns an async function.
2. You cannot get a `value` directly from this function. You need to run it first and get `DOMNodeState` which has the `value` property.

As a result. your `claimid` assigning should be done as follows `claimid= await global.ClaimNumber().value`