# How to pass a web element value from one Testscripts to another Testscripts in testcafe

Tags: javascript, global-variables, testcafe

In our insurance domain, the below scenario we want to achieve using testcafe:

**1st file:** Login into the application

**2nd file:** Create a claim, store the claim number into the global variable

**3rd file:** Use that globally declared claim number in all the Test scripts.

We are using the Page object model to achieve our scenario.

Please let us know how can we achieve this in testcafe. As we suspect, the web element value that we get in 2nd file gets vanished as soon as the test case gets executed. so how can we pass that web element value in our 3rd file? If possible, please let us know the steps in detail.

we have tried the below keywords to define our selector but it didn't work.

```
global

globalthis
```

We want to pass the data (fetched web element value) from one testscript to another testscript. Our question is whether it's possible or not

```
//page.js

import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'; class PageModel { constructor() { global.ClaimNumber = Selector('#Txt_claimnumber'); //selector for Claim Number

this.DateOfEvent = Selector('#dateofevent'); //selector for Date of Event

this.DateOfClaim = Selector('#dateofclaim') //selector for Date of Claim

this.TimeOfEvent = Selector('#timeofevent') //selector for Time of Event

this.TimeOfClaim = Selector('#timeofclaim') //selector for Time of Claim

this.ClaimStatus = Selector('#claimstatus') //selector for Claim Status

this.Save = Selector('#Save'); //selector for Save Button

}};

export default new PageModel();

//test.js

import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

import PageModel from './page';

fixtureGetting Started

.pagehttps://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example;

var claimid;//claimid will be generated after saving a claim

test('My first test', async t => { await t .typeText(this.DateOfEvent, '20/09/2022')

.typeText(this.DateOfClaim, '20/09/2022')

.typeText(this.TimeOfEvent, '12:00')

.typeText(this.TimeOfClaim, '12:00')

.typeText(this.ClaimStatus, 'xyz')

.click(this.Save)

claimid=global.ClaimNumber.value

//After saving the claim we want to fetch claimid and want to use that claim id in another test scripts

});

//test1.js

import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

import PageModel from './page';

import Test from './test'

fixtureGetting Started

.pagehttps://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example;

test('My first test', async t => {

var claimid1='23445'; await t.expect(claimid1).eql('claimid');

//want to verify claimid getting from test.js is equal to claimid from test1.js or not

//this is just an example but our requirement is to use claimid (getting from test.js) for different operations into test1.js testscript.

});
```

Could you please tell us how to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store web element&#39;s value in a parameter and use it in various js files in testcafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662901/store-web-element39s-value-in-a-parameter-and-use-it-in-various-js-files-in-t)

Answer (score 1):

It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662901/store-web-element39s-value-in-a-parameter-and-use-it-in-various-js-files-in-t/73686079#73686079). As I wrote to you, there is a mistake in the example. You cannot get a selector value in this way globally. `ClaimNumber.value` because of the following:

1. To execute the selector, you need to call it with `await` because `Selector('#Text_claim number')` returns an async function.
2. You cannot get a value directly from this function. You need to run it first and get [DOMNodeState](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402670/reference/test-api/domnodestate) that has the value property. As a result. your `claimid` assigning should be done as follows: `claimid = await global.ClaimNumber().value`